# Gnuplot plotting 3d points and annotating

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I am trying to plot 3D points using GnuPlot.

What I want to achieve is a picture like this (which I plotted using matplotlib)-

[image]

My code is -

```
set datafile separator "," 
set view 60,80
set autoscale
set parametric
set style data points
splot 'normal.csv' with points
splot 'left_edge.csv' with points
set view 29,53 #Done implicitly by mousing.
set term pngcairo mono enhanced
set xlabel "Latency"
set ylabel "Processors"
set zlabel "Buffer Size"
set out 'bessel.png'
replot
```

What I so far achieved is like this -

[image]

I am a beginner to Gnu plot. 
I want to know if I could achieve this kind of result?
It is difficult to get started with less information.

Comment: I don't know if this is still on-topic. You can use plotting style `with labels` to print the values, and `with vectors` to plot the arrows. In your plotting script you have two `splot` commands, and one `replot`... If you are still interested in an answer and show the data, I can show you how to plot that with `gnuplot`.

Comment: @Christoph thanks a lot for your response. I have forgotten about this question. but I generated the first image using `matplotlib`. I think that `gnuplot` wont generate equally good graph. if you show me how to do it, it will definitely add to my knowledge. thanks a lot !

Comment: You can find relevant tutorials on labels and vectors/arrows here: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/cities.html , http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/vector.html , http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/lines_arrows.html